# c: pointers - how to increase every 2nd byte by X

Tags: c, memset

I have a pointer that's holding 100 bytes of data.
i would like to add 5 to every 2nd byte.

example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

will become:

```
1 7 3 9 5 11
```

Now i know i can do a for loop, is there a quicker way? something like memset that will increase the value of every 2nd byte ?

thanks

Comment: For the life of me I can't get `gcc -O3 -ftree-vectorize` to vectorize the loop.  "not vectorized: complicated access pattern" (from `--tree-vectorizer-verbose=9`).  If I increment *every* value it does it just fine.  It even says "Detected single element interleaving".  I've written the loop every way I can think of.f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop would be the best way. memset() is efficient for setting a contiguous block of memory. Wouldn't be much help for you here.

Answer (score 2):

In which format do you have your bytes? As concatenated chars? Or are the bytes a subpart of e.g. a uint32?

In general, a loop is the best way for doing this - even if you would be able to apply a pattern-like mask with memset, you would still need to create it and that would take the same amount of CPU cycles.

If you would have 4 bytes per element (e.g. uint32), you could cut the cpu cycles in half by creating a pre-defined mask for adding. But attention: such a solution would not check for overflows (pseudocode):

```
uint32* ptr = new uint32[16]; // creates 64 bytes of data
(...) fill data
for (int k=0; k < 16; ++k)
{
   // Hardcored Add-Mask for Little Endian systems
   ptr[k] += 0x05000500; // dereference and add mask to content
}
```

Edit: Please note that this assumes a little endian system and is C++ Pseudocode.

Comment: the size of the bytes is 1 byte, 8 bits.  not integer or anything. but still good point.

Comment: right, but you can store four bytes = 32 bit in a uint32, which would be (depending on the memory alignment) the more effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

If `memset` supported increasing the value of every nth byte, how do you think it would accomplish it?

Comment: memset does not increase current value but sets it. what's your point? how is this comment gonna assist me in any way ?

Comment: This may not be the best answer, but what he's trying to tell you is that IF memset() did what you ask (it does not), it would have to do that with a loop, just like you would.

Comment: the point is you asked for quicker than a loop, like memset.  What makes you think memset isn't looping?

Comment: @Jon: yeah it appears so. it wasn't clear for me at all before dicroce explained it.

Comment: Given that `memset` is often fiendishly optimized in platform-specific ways, I'm pretty sure that a standard library function that does what the questioner wants would not be implemented the same way as the for loop the questioner has in mind. Since it doesn't exist, we can't be entirely sure whether it would be an optimization target for implementers, but based on the ones I've known, they would not long resist having a go at it in assembly of a Friday afternoon, *not* using a for loop written in C.

Comment: @Steve: +1 for the point of view... brings older days to mind. But today, I 'd be really surprised to see a decent compiler out-optimized by a human in a simple variation of a for loop. And of course all this is of philosophical interest only unless we 're talking about the inner loop of a CPU-bound process.

Comment: @Jon: given Ben Jackson's report that GCC failed to vectorize any of his versions of this, I think you're over-estimating compilers. And in particular, standard functions are fiendishly optimized *by the same people who write compilers*, so it's not as if the compiler knows any tricks that they don't. It can apply its tricks faster and in more combinations, but when its tricks fail, these are the people who invent new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact make it faster by using loop unrolling, but you'll need to know that your array is a fixed size.  Then you would skip the loop overhead by just repeatedly assigning the value:

```
array[ 1 ] += 5;
array[ 3 ] += 5;
array[ 5 ] += 5;
...
```

By doing this you don't have the overhead incurred by jump and test instructions that would be present in a loop, but you pay for it in code bloat.

Comment: On the DSP architecture I program for (ADI's Blackfin), we have a Zero Overhead Loop mechanism which eliminates the overhead incurred by the test and jump. It is done in hardware in a predictive form, so no penalty is paid. I am not familiar with the x86 architecture, but I bet it is similar there.